# Gerar uma url de busca?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Preciso pegar a url de busca por um termo específico em um site construído usando CodeIgniter. Mas quando digito o termo, a url muda somente para: `nomedosite.com.br/busca`

Tentei acrescentar `?q=arquitetura` mas não funcionou.

Comment: Como é a action `busca` no seu controller?

Answer (score 3):

Você está querendo dizer: Passar parâmetros via URL?
Se for isso mesmo, cheque em seu arquivo de configuração em 
`application/config/config.php` se está habilitado a opção de query strings.

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
```

Se estiver ***false***, você não vai conseguir fazer isso.

Para mais informações, segue o link:

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Answer (score 0):

O codeigniter foi projetado para trabalhar com url amigáveis

```
www.site.com/curso/buscar/arquitetura
```

sugiro que você veja este tópico http://codeigniterbrasil.com/passos-iniciais/urls-no-codeigniter/